Flutter deferred components gradle build failed
I'm trying to build a flutter app with deferred components to implement a kind of plugin system for my mobile app. I've followed the steps on https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components, and I've got to the point where I have copied all generated files into my project and the deferred components validation has passed. But when I run flutter build appbundle I get the following error in the 'android/build.gradle':
Deferred components prebuild validation passed.

Shrinking has been disabled for this build due to deferred components. Shrinking is not available for multi-apk applications. This limitation is expected to be removed when Gradle plugin 4.2+ is available in Flutter.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Nosa\Coding\Bachelorarbeit\app_with_plugins\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Unable to find matching projects for Dynamic Features: [:plugin_one]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 739ms
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           1.369ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I skipped Step 1.2 because (as far as I understand it) it's only needed when you want to use the Google Play Store as your distribution model, which I am currently not planning to do.
Flutter doctor shows no errors or warnings:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3810], locale de-DE)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!

I am providing a minimal reproducible example on github under https://github.com/nomoruyi/app_with_plugins
EDIT:
I now changed a few things, manly just by trial and error, but also got some info from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Deferred-Components. I think I am closer to the solution, but I get a different error now:
Deferred components prebuild validation passed.

Shrinking has been disabled for this build due to deferred components. Shrinking is not available for multi-apk applications. This limitation is expected to be removed when Gradle plugin 4.2+ is available in Flutter.
C:\Users\Nosa\Coding\Bachelorarbeit\app_with_plugins\android\plugin_one\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Users\Nosa\Coding\Bachelorarbeit\app_with_plugins\android\plugin_one\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Users\Nosa\Coding\Bachelorarbeit\app_with_plugins\android\plugin_one\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plugin_one:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           2.355ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I can't set the Android SDK to <=30 because then AndroidX does't work anymore. It says I should add exported="true" to three elements in my plugins manifest file, but there are no activity tags inside that file.
This new version is on the dev branch of the aforementioned github repo.
